# Error installing oracle java 8 on my ubuntu machine

Tags: java

I am getting this error while installing oracle-java8 on my ubuntu machine
Can someone help me with this

**sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk8-installer**

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...", 
"--2018-03-24 08:08:59--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz", 
"Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.46.60.117", 
"Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.46.60.117|:80... connected.", 
"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily", 
"Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/ [following]",
"--2018-03-24 08:08:59--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/", 
"Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.91.45.157, 2600:1408:2000:198::2d3e, 2600:1408:2000:197::2d3e", 
"Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.91.45.157|:443... connected.", 
"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
```

Comment: See the error: `302 Moved Temporarily`. Try instructions from the [here](https://medium.com/coderscorner/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-10-845507b13343)

Comment: It was runni g fews days back and now not running

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions but still the same issue

Comment: So what have changed in your environment since you last ran this successfully?

Comment: I am using ansible. Tried manually as well. Nothing changed. Have you tried running this on a ubuntu machine recently?

Comment: Why is it down voted when the site is down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle site is broken. Go to Oracle's download page for Java8 and try manually (oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/…) You get a 404 on all links.

It doesn't help to use the installer from webupd8team since that one also just accesses Oracle's site, neither does it help to patch the installer like in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686.

Comment: Any expected ETA to fix