# Java JDK - 404 when downloading for macOS

Tags: java, macos, java-8, homebrew

I want to learn Java and I can't download Java JDK 8. When I try to download it I have a 404 error. It's Oracle site problem or what?

I tried to download it using Homebrew `brew cask install java` but it's the same problem:

> Error: Download failed on Cask 'java' with message: Download failed:
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/10+46/76eac37278c24557a3c4199677f19b62/jdk-10_osx-x64_bin.dmg

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464208/error-installing-oracle-java-8-on-my-ubuntu-machine

Comment: By the way, you have many choices of vendor for getting a Java implementation on macOS including (in no particular order): AdoptOpenJDK, Amazon Coretto, Oracle JDK, Oracle build of OpenJDK, Oracle GraalVM, Zulu by Azul Systems, Zing by Azul Systems,, BellSoft Liberica, Alibaba Dragonwell, Red Hat build of OpenJDK, Pivotal Distribution of OpenJDK, and SapMachine by SAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today but I found this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html?printOnly=1 and I can download it! first you must create and Oracle account